# Segmentation Fault

Tags: c

Eu gostaria de alocar memória dinamicamente sem informar a quantidade de elementos que um vetor teria.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cardinalidade(char *conjunto)
{
    int contador = 0, indice = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        if (conjunto[indice] == ' ') // Se o elemento analisado for ' ' entao este foi o ultimo elemento.
        {
            break; 
        }

    }

    indice++;
    contador++; // Conta o numero de elementos no vetor.

    return contador;
}

 char *criaConjunto()
 {
       char flag = '!', *conjunto;
       int indice = 0;

       while (flag != '@')
       {
           printf("ELEMENTO %i: ", indice + 1);
           scanf("%c", &flag); // Armazeno o valor lido em uma variavel temporária.

           indice++; // Foi lido mais um elemento.

           conjunto = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * indice);  // Aloco um vetor de n posições(depende do numero de elementos preenchidos)
           conjunto[indice] = flag; // Coloco o valor lido anteriormente no conjunto.
        }

        conjunto[indice + 1] = ' '; // Ultimo elemento será o elemento indicando o fim do conjunto.

       return conjunto; // Retornando o endereço do primeiro elemento do conjunto
}

int main()
{
    char *A = criaConjunto();

    printf("|A| = %i", cardinalidade(A));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O caminho é usar [`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) no lugar de `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como já indicado o correto é utilizar [`realloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/), que assim pode ir pedindo os elementos da forma que já está a pedir, e vai aumentando o tamanho do vetor à medida que recebe elementos.

Incorporando no seu código ficaria assim:

```
char flag = '!', *conjunto = NULL; //o vetor tem de ser inicializado a NULL
int indice = 0;

while (flag != '@')
{
    printf("ELEMENTO %i: ", indice + 1);
    scanf(" %c", &flag);
    //     ^--- este espaço antes serve para consumir a quebra de linha

    conjunto = (char *) realloc (conjunto, sizeof(char) * (indice + 1)); //realloc aqui
    conjunto[indice] = flag;
    indice++;//incremento tem de vir no fim senão o 1 elemento vai para a posição 1 e não 0
}
```

No `realloc` é indicado qual o vetor a ser realocado, que no exemplo é o `conjunto`, e para que tamanho vai ser realocado. Na primeira vez o `realloc` é chamado com o vetor `NULL`, e nesse caso comporta-se como um [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/). Repare que tive que mudar o incremento do `indice` para o fim do `while` para garantir que o primeiro elemento é guardado na posição `0`, mas mantendo a alocação com o tamanho correto, que é `indice + 1`.

Faltou também atribuir o fim da string com o terminador correto o `\0`, e garantir existe espaço para ele. Uma vez que de acordo com o seu algoritmo também quer colocar um espaço, então pode fazer assim:

```
//+2 => reservaço tamanho para o espaço e terminador
conjunto = (char *) realloc (NULL, sizeof(char) * (indice + 2)); 
conjunto[indice++] = ' '; 
conjunto[indice] = '\0'; //coloca o terminador no fim
```

Com o terminador já poderá imprimir o vetor num `printf`, se assim o desejar.

Apenas como nota final, repare que tem um `while` efetivamente infinito na função `cardinalidade`:

```
while (1)
{
    if (conjunto[indice] == ' ') // Se o elemento analisado for ' ' entao este foi o ultimo elemento.
    {
        break; 
    }
}
```

Como o `indice` não é incrementando, este `while` nunca vai terminar, pois nunca sai do mesmo caratere. Para alem disso não tem nenhuma contagem lá dentro que é o que eu suspeito que queria fazer.